# warning: "IPPROTO_TCP" redefined warning: this is the location of the previous definition

Tags: c++, linux

I am getting this warning when compiling

In file included from server.c:48:

> unixwin.h:23:1: warning: "IPPROTO_TCP"
>   redefined In file included from
>   server.c:42:
>   /usr/include/netinet/in.h:45:1:
>   warning: this is the location of the
>   previous definition

below is the sections refered to in the error:

```
file unixwin.h
15
 16 #ifndef FALSE
 17 #define FALSE 0
 18 #endif
 19
 20 #define SOCKADDR_IN struct sockaddr_in
 21 #define SOCKET_ERROR -1
 22 #define INVALID_SOCKET (SOCKET)(~0)
 23 #define IPPROTO_TCP 6
 24 #define LPSOCKADDR struct sockaddr *
 25 #define GMEM_MOVEABLE 1
 26 #define GMEM_FIXED 2
 27 #define GMEM_SHARE 3
 28 #define GPTR 4
 29 #define LPHOSTENT struct hostent *
 30 #define LPIN_ADDR struct in_addr *
 31
 32 #ifndef UINT
 33 #define UINT unsigned int
 34 #endif
 35
```

In file server.c

```
37
  38 #ifdef UNIX
  39 #include <sys/types.h>
  40 #include <sys/socket.h>
  41 #include <sys/ioctl.h>
  42 #include <netinet/in.h>
  43 #include <arpa/inet.h>
  44 #include <time.h>
  45 #ifndef FIONREAD
  46 #include <sys/filio.h>
  47 #endif
  48 #include "unixwin.h"
  49 #endif
  50
```

And in file /usr/include/netinet/in.h

```
30
 31 /* Standard well-defined IP protocols.  */
 32 enum
 33   {
 34     IPPROTO_IP = 0,        /* Dummy protocol for TCP.  */
 35 #define IPPROTO_IP              IPPROTO_IP
 36     IPPROTO_HOPOPTS = 0,   /* IPv6 Hop-by-Hop options.  */
 37 #define IPPROTO_HOPOPTS         IPPROTO_HOPOPTS
 38     IPPROTO_ICMP = 1,      /* Internet Control Message Protocol.  */
 39 #define IPPROTO_ICMP            IPPROTO_ICMP
 40     IPPROTO_IGMP = 2,      /* Internet Group Management Protocol. */
 41 #define IPPROTO_IGMP            IPPROTO_IGMP
 42     IPPROTO_IPIP = 4,      /* IPIP tunnels (older KA9Q tunnels use 94).  */
 43 #define IPPROTO_IPIP            IPPROTO_IPIP
 44     IPPROTO_TCP = 6,       /* Transmission Control Protocol.  */
 45 #define IPPROTO_TCP             IPPROTO_TCP
 46     IPPROTO_EGP = 8,       /* Exterior Gateway Protocol.  */
 47 #define IPPROTO_EGP             IPPROTO_EGP
 48     IPPROTO_PUP = 12,      /* PUP protocol.  */
 49 #define IPPROTO_PUP             IPPROTO_PUP
 50     IPPROTO_UDP = 17,      /* User Datagram Protocol.  */
 51 #define IPPROTO_UDP             IPPROTO_UDP
 52     IPPROTO_IDP = 22,      /* XNS IDP protocol.  */
 53 #define IPPROTO_IDP             IPPROTO_IDP
 54     IPPROTO_TP = 29,       /* SO Transport Protocol Class 4.  */
 55 #define IPPROTO_TP              IPPROTO_TP
 56     IPPROTO_IPV6 = 41,     /* IPv6 header.  */
 57 #define IPPROTO_IPV6            IPPROTO_IPV6
 58     IPPROTO_ROUTING = 43,  /* IPv6 routing header.  */
 59 #define IPPROTO_ROUTING         IPPROTO_ROUTING
 60     IPPROTO_FRAGMENT = 44, /* IPv6 fragmentation header.  */
```

Can you say where the text is wrong
thanks